# Authorise a Execute the app as user accessing the web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a webapp that's deployed as Execute the app as user accessing the web app

This means it will always show the Authorization prompt the first time it's being used.

I want to use this webapp as a webhook to receive sms and store in my spreadsheet

I dont want to make the spreadsheet anyone with link can edit and don't want to make the app as anyone even anonymous deployed.

I am asking whether a Execute the app as user accessing the web app can be authorised by calling a urlfetchapp via parameters?

Comment: Try the oauth library with credentials stored to script properties

Comment: I want to Authorize a web app via auth token passed as get request. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. But why do you want to authorize the web app through tokens, when you can authorize through  the browser?

Comment: I am using the webhook url for receiving sms and place in data to spreadsheet. The same webhook will be used by several other users just by changing the url parameters like the spreadsheet id

Comment: If I make deploy anyone access all other users sms come to my sheet. I want respective user sms go to their own sheets

Comment: So make them authorize the webapp through the browser? Why you need a auth token? ( Side note: A web sequence diagram to show the flow would greatly improve your question)

Comment: I love the question, but I am missing the master plan. You mean, you have a server that receives SMS and then calls your WebApp via URL with the SMS content as parameter and your WebApp inserts it into a spreadsheet? Then there is no browser involved.

Comment: As @TheMaster says, it would be helpful if you would provide a diagram of how your WebApp works. In any case, you could check [this library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) that helps you to handle OAuth token creation inside Google Apps Script.